# How to unit test if something is !== using jasmine and check flag?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-unit-test

Hey so I have this method in my Angular app which I want to unit test:

```
public methodEquip(someBonus: Parameters) {
    let flag = false;
    for (const shield of someBonus.items) {
        if (shield.added.length !== 0 || shield.removed.length !== 0) {
            flag = true
        }
        if (flag) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to unit test it with Jasmine. I can do simple unit tests but it's too much for me now, I'm stucked. I'm quite new to unit tests and I don't know how to do it :/
Can you help me?

I have only this for now, and I don't know how to do the rest of it:

```
it('tests methodEquip', () => {
       let flag = false;
       const newMocked = new Parameters;
       component.methodEquip(newMocked);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jasmine, any `matcher` can evaluate to a negative assertion by chaining the call to `expect` with a `not` before calling the `matcher`.

For primitive types (boolean, number, string etc.):

```
expect(actual).not.toBe(x);
```

For objects:

```
expect(actual).not.toEqual(x);
```

In your case, the test could look as follows:

```
it('#methodEquip should not return false when ...', () => {
    const parameters = new Parameters;
    const actual = component.methodEquip(parameters);
    expect(actual).not.toBe(false);
});
```

> Since `boolean` has only two possible values, it would however make more sense to simply write `expect(actual).toBe(true)`;

Comment: Can I manipluate length value to check other options? Does it make sense or this single test should be enough?

Comment: You typically write 1-n unit tests per method to make sure all different code branches are executed at least ones and produce the expected results.

Comment: I got error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" with this test case, I'm looking for some tips right now